# C++ Calling overwritten function in derived from base class

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I have 2 classes, `A` and `B` and I need an overwritten function in `B` to be called from `A`'s constructor. Here is what I have already:

```
class A {
    A(char* str) {
        this->foo();
    }

    virtual void foo(){}
}

class B : public A {
    B(char* str) : A(str) {}

    void foo(){
        //stuff here isn't being called
    }
}
```

How would I get code to be called in `B::foo()` from `A::A()`?

Comment: Do not use virtual functions in constructors., When B is being constructed, A gets constructed first. At this point the extra methods/variables for B have not been set up. So things can go terribly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need an overwritten function in B to be called from A's constructor

This design is not possible in C++: the [order of construction](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/113-order-of-construction-of-derived-classes/) of a B object is that first the base A sub-object is constructed, then B is constructed on top of it.

The consequence is that, while in A constructor, you are still constructing an A object: any virtual function called at this point will be the one for A.  Only when the A construction is finished and the B construction starts, will the virtual functions of B become effective.

For achieveing what you want, you have to use a two step pattern:  1) you construct the object, 2) you initialize it.

Comment: Good. I think a good further note is needed here, which also explains _why_ this is C++'s design; that is, that it's dangerous to make assumptions about the contents of virtual functions and their expectations (e.g. that some members are already initialized).

Comment: @YamMarcovic the rational of base-first logic is explained by Bjarne Stroustrup in "Design & Evolution of C++", p283: if the overriden function would be callled during the construction, it would not know which members are already constructed or not, and every overriden function would have to be written with the utmost care and paranoia reserved for constructors.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant--sorry if it wasn't clear. I think it could be a good addition to the answer to mention it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are referring to Calling Virtuals During Initialization Idiom (aka Dynamic Binding During Initialization), so please have a look here, where everything is explained:

1. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Calling_Virtuals_During_Initialization
2. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom

2nd site has very good explanation, but it's way longer than 1st.

Comment: Sadly this won't work out for me, it was interesting though, thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain why? Perhaps I can help.

Comment: It's a specific case to me, the specific constructor I have in my base class goes something like `init variables -> make objects -> run loop` and so the function I was trying to use was make objects. So instead I flipped around my base class to have 2 functions `init()` and `start()` and in between function calls I call `makeObjects()`

Answer (score 1):

In a constructor, the base class' function will get called, not the overridden version. The reason for this is that, using your example, `B`'s initialization is not complete when `A`'s constructor is called, and thus calling `B`'s `foo` would be done with an incomplete `B` instance if this were otherwise allowed.